# How to merge unmanaged DLLs and images with managed DLL?

Tags: dll, unmanaged, managed

I want to merge unmanaged DLLs and image files with managed DLL. How I can do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite possible. This can be done with [bxilmerge](https://github.com/boxedapp/bxilmerge)
This solution can to merge unmanaged DLLs and images or another files with managed DLL